# Способы просмотра полей которые хранятся в массиве. Bitrix

Tags: php, битрикс

Подскажите способы вывода информации, которая храниться в переменной массива. var_dump(), print_r() если использовать их из под админки в инфоблоках ломают весь сайт.

Comment: Чтобы не ломали сайт, нужно использовать буфер `ob_start()`, а не писать велосипеды.

Comment: @And , Можете привести пример (кусочек кода, где этот буфер используется в bitrix)?

Comment: Пожалуйста, прочитайте документацию по функции `ob_start` на оф. сайте `php.net` - и вопросы отпадут.

Answer (score 0):

Я подключаю в composer.json [leeoniya/dump-r](https://packagist.org/packages/leeoniya/dump-r)

```
php composer.phar require leeoniya/dump-r dev-master
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нашёл в своё время в [блогах битрикс](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/community/webdev/user/137665/blog/8863/?last_comment_id=0&comment_post_id=8863&LAST_LOG_TS=0&PAGEN_1=1), понравилось.